# Getting persistence.xml error while integrating jBPM 5.4 into a J2EE web app

Tags: maven, jboss, jbpm

I have been having trouble getting "jBPM integrated into a web app" while using Eclipse (Kepler).  As a test I am simply trying to replicate the code found in the jBPM Full Installer's evaluation sample into the template code produced by a Maven JavaEE6 Archetype.  I have noted my steps below so that the problem can be easily reproduced.

1) Add to the JBoss standalone.xml:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/jdbc/jbpm-ds" pool-name="jBPMDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
    <driver>h2</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>sa</user-name>
        <password>sa</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

2) JBoss Central > Maven Project > filter on "javaee6" (to create the "myservlet" Project):
    Archetype = jboss-javaee6-webapp
    Accept all defaults

3) Set src\main\resources\META-INF\persistence.xml to contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
      <!-- If you are running in a production environment, add a managed 
         data source, the example data source is just for proofs of concept! -->
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

4) Add a jBPM Runtime by pointing at the \runtime folder from the jBPM Full Installer.

5) Select the jBPM Perspective, right click the myservlet Project > Convert to jBPM Project.

6) Add to the Deployment Assembly the Java Build Path Entries > jBPM Library.

7) In src\main\java\com\mycompany\mywebapp\controller add to (arbitrarily chosen) MemberRegistration.java (which was automatically created as part of the Project) the following which comes from the evaluation sample code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.drools.KnowledgeBase;
import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilder;
import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory;
import org.drools.builder.ResourceType;
import org.drools.io.ResourceFactory;
import org.drools.logger.KnowledgeRuntimeLogger;
import org.drools.logger.KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory;
import org.drools.runtime.StatefulKnowledgeSession;
import org.jbpm.process.workitem.wsht.HornetQHTWorkItemHandler;
```

8) In this same module, in register() add the following which also comes from the evaluation sample code:

```
 try {
    // load up the knowledge base
    KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("Evaluation.bpmn"), ResourceType.BPMN2);
    KnowledgeBase kbase = kbuilder.newKnowledgeBase();
    StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
    HornetQHTWorkItemHandler humanTaskHandler = new HornetQHTWorkItemHandler(ksession);
    humanTaskHandler.setIpAddress("127.0.0.1");
    humanTaskHandler.setPort(5153);
    ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Human Task", humanTaskHandler);
    KnowledgeRuntimeLogger logger = KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory.newThreadedFileLogger(ksession, "test", 1000);
    // start a new process instance
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("employee", "krisv");
    params.put("reason", "Yearly performance evaluation");
    ksession.startProcess("com.sample.evaluation", params);
    System.out.println("Process started ...");
    logger.close();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

Upon deploying along with the six jBPM WARs we get this error:
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS011470: Persistence unitName was not specified and there are 2 persistence unit definitions in application deployment "myservlet.war".  Either change the application to have only one persistence unit definition or specify the unitName for each reference to a persistence unit.

I have confirmed that there is exactly one persistence.xml file anywhere in the deployed myservlet folder (it is in jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\myservlet.war\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF).

Can someone explain what this error means and how to eliminate it?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that somewhere along all those configured .xml you made some mistake that's not that clear. I know how much a pain in the a** that can be. I've written a small tutorial on how to configure persistence for JBPM using JBoss AS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913905/configuring-persistence-and-orm-with-jpa-2/14769700#14769700). I suggest you follow it step by step to re-configure your project.

Hope it solves your problem!