# Good online resources for JPA 2 orm.xml

Tags: java, xml, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

I've been trying to find some good online resources for learning how to write a mapping/orm.xml for JPA 2.

I'm finding it just impossible.  All examples are either for an earlier version, or they simply aren't there.  It seems like using annotations is so popular that no one is writing examples for doing the mapping in XML.

Personally, I'd prefer to do the mapping in XML simply because I feel like otherwise I'm adding an unnecessary coupling between JPA and classes that are just simple data holding classes.

Anyway - can anyone recommend any decent online resources for JPA orm.xml?

Comment: This is an off-topic question for the site. I had the same feeling towards this, tho, and just have to learn jpa from the resources I found on the net, writing code and solving any odd exception that raised in the way.

Comment: Why is this off-topic? Also, my problem is that I can't really find any resources on the net - hence the question!

Comment: Because *Questions asking us **to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it*

Comment: [Off Topic Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: fair enough - my problem is that I don't know how to write orm.xml, although I can do annotations and I can't find any resources! :-)

Comment: Your problem is a valid problem, and your question is a valid question, but it's just not appropriate for this site. And I wish I knew of an appropriate site, but I don't. Perhaps there are books that could help you with this? Regardless, you should probably delete this question. Keep searching though, and good luck.

Comment: Here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/persisting-entity-classes, https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/xml-overriding.html, https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html (use a search function in your browser and look for XML for this link), here at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913905/configuring-persistence-and-orm-with-jpa-2

Comment: I think there are always exceptions to the rule and a request for the -official- Oracle specifications of the orm.xml file is not a bad question to ask on SO. I find it a rather intriguing question as I can't seem to find it anywhere either.

Comment: @Gimby: this issue has been discussed to death on meta. Whether or not a question is intriguing has nothing to do with whether it is on-topic or not. I would find a full discussion on the pro's and cons of national health insurance intriguing and helpful, but that doesn't make it appropriate for SO.

Comment: Huh? http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_1/jpa/metadata_xml.html  describes everything I've needed to use

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I will take a small amount of time to make a note of the links given so far and will then delete the question to avoid further arguments.

Comment: OK - I'm about to mine these links, so this thread won't be around much longer.  Having thought about it, though, I fail to see the problem with this question since it doesn't invite opinionated answers - imho!  If I had asked which JPA implementation I should use then, yes, but asking for useful links seems harmless to me. That said, I'll abide by the wishes of the community and remove the thread shortly.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels not a fair comparison, health care has nothing to do with software engineering or programming specifically; this does. But thanks for turning my choice of words against me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an off-topic question.

I usually consider the following link as a bible for all the annotations that I need. It has all the annotations that are in JPA 1.0 and 2.0 and small description of each annotation. Also, You may need to research in the internet if the description is not enough for you.

http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa

Also there is a good PDF document available in the oracle site [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html). It also has very good information on JPA 2.1.

Comment: errm, he's asking about XML *not* annotations.